# Theology of self-realisation of God?

Tags: catholicism, nature-of-god, christian-psychology

According to Maslow, the self-realisation is the ultimate happiness of the Man. Man is created according to the God's image. Does God have self-realisation activities? Especially I am interested in Roman Catholic teaching.

Comment: God is by definition as realized as he can be.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, he's pure actuality (_actus purus_); cf. the [1st of the 24 Thomistic Theses](http://scholastic.us.to/24Thomisticpart2.htm#thesis1).

Comment: @Geremia how about maybe making that an answer, rather than a comment?  I think it would be worth having in our collection of good answers.

Answer (score 1):

## Man's ultimate happiness is found in God.

I don't know what Maslow means by "self-realization", but man's ultimate happiness is not found in man but in God:

> St. Thomas Aquinas wrote 32 questions on happiness (*felicitas*) in his Treatise on Man's Last End ([*Summa Theologica* I-II](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS.html) qq. 1-5) or purpose, which he says is twofold:
>
> - to attain happiness, which is "the acquisition of the last end" or purpose ([*ibid.* q. 1 a. 8](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS001.html#FSQ1A8THEP1))
>
> and
>
> - happiness itself, which is the last end.
>
> cf. also his commentary on [Aristotle's *Ethics* bk. 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Ethics1.htm#1), which is on happiness
>
> ---
>
> <sup>[source](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/39827/2014)</sup>

## *Does God have self-realisation activities?*

This reminds me of what St. Augustine wrote about the processions of the Persons of the Trinity in his [*On the Trinity* book 10](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/130110.htm), "Chapter 12.— The Mind is an Image of the Trinity in Its Own Memory, and Understanding, and Will."